# Setting up a table for multiple levels of ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

We have reports set up on our customer's site with various kinds of data.  The structure of most reports is something like:

```
Headers
[Group 1 rows]
Group 1 totals
[Group 2 rows]
Group 2 totals
...
[Group x rows]
Group x totals
Grand totals
```

We accomplish this in a table using something like this

```
<table>
<th>...</th>
<tbody ng-repeat="group in data">
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">...</tr>
<tr>group totals</tr>
</tbody>
<tr>grand totals</tr>
</table>
```

I have a report I'm trying to design that has multiple levels of looping needed. The structure would look more like this:

```
Headers
| [Group 1.1.1 rows]
| Group 1.1.1 totals
| [Group 1.1.2 rows]
| Group 1.1.2 totals
Group 1.1 Totals
| [Group 1.2.1 rows]
| Group 1.2.1 totals
| [Group 1.2.2 rows]
| Group 1.2.2 totals
Group 1.2 Totals
Group 1 Totals
...
| [Group x.1.1 rows]
| Group x.1.1 totals
| [Group x.1.2 rows]
| Group x.1.2 totals
Group x.1 Totals
Group x Totals
Grand Totals
```

I know Tbodys cannot be nested. I was looking to avoid multiple tables because it would be a huge pain to have all the columns line up correctly. Any known solution to something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not render each group as its own table and control the column width with css? You could even use an angular expression to get a dynamic td width dependant on your data columns.

```
<ANY class="ng-style: ;"> ... </ANY>
```

e.g.

```
<section ng-repeat="group in data">
    <table class="dataTables">
    <th>...</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">...</tr>
        <tr>group totals</tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```